# How do I add packages to Standalone Qgis's Python?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-2.8, windows-8.1

I have installed the QGIS 2.8 on my Windows 8.1 system, using the Standalone Installer.

I now wish to install the [VectorBender plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VectorBender/). 
The [docs](https://github.com/olivierdalang/VectorBender) for this plugin say, that I need to install `matplotlib 1.3.0`, and it's dependencies first.

How do I install these dependencies?

Comment: [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) is a Python module and it is preinstalled by the Standalone installer. (in QGIS.x/Apps/Python/lib/site_packages)

Comment: @gene: Can you post that as an answer? Because of you, I didn't have to do anything, and it just worked!

Comment: done, I post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) is a Python module and it is preinstalled by the Standalone installer. (in QGIS.x/Apps/Python/lib/site_packages)